# Error Unable to retrieve topology component health states. This may be because the admin component is not up and running

Tags: search

After an outage and after bringing up all the services back online.

The Search Server Application : Search Admin cant find all the search application topology.

It's showing error :

> Unable to retrieve topology component health states. This may be because the admin component is not up and running.

Looking at the event logs i can see error:

> A failure was reported when trying to invoke a service application: EndpointFailure for http://XXXX/ccc/SearchService.svc

When I click on the link endpoint it works.

Do I need to re-provision this for it to work or the services needs to be rebooted in a particular sequence?

There is  a 2 web server , 2 app server and one OWA

Comment: Can you check whether the WSS Usage Application Proxy is stopped? If so, use the following PowerShell to start it, then try accessing the Search Service Application again: 
$WUP = get-spserviceapplicationproxy | where {$_.typename -like "Usage*"}
$WUP.provision()

Comment: Just to clarify, there are two commands beginning '$WUP' shown above; these should be run as separate commands, not run together as they are shown.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same error in SP2016, in my Search service Administration page , I have seen this error in admin page

> Unable to retrieve topology component health states. This may be because the admin component is not up and running

After that i tried to bring the Admin component by various tricks, tried to check whether all app pool is running .

and ran IIS reset and that does not help.

I tried to create another Search service Application , that too did not help.

after that I noticed that "SPSearchHostController" service was not running fine.

Then I restarted the machine , that finally helped the "SPSearchHostController" made to Automatic Mode and up and running.

[Reference-Link1](https://redcrust.wordpress.com/2014/12/18/unable-to-retrieve-topology-component-health-states-this-may-be-because-the-admin-component-is-not-up-and-running/)

[Reference-Link2](http://moresharepoints.blogspot.in/2015/07/search-has-encountered-problem-that.html)

[Reference-Link3](https://leonzandman.com/2012/11/08/return-of-the-search-application-topology-component-health-state-error/)